# Rewrite URLs with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite my URLs so they are search engine friendly.

Example URL is:

```
http://www.example.com/?Products=Displays&SubCat=Chalkboards-and-Accessories&Item=Budget-Framed-Chalkboards
```

I am thinking maybe something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/Chalkboards-and-Accessories/Budget-Framed-Chalkboards
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: quite a few different ways but none of them have any affect or change

Comment: You are making people waste their time answering your question while you play to solve to other problems making questions in the comments. That's not fair and it is not the way questions are solved in SO. If you make a question you should look for an answer to your question, not for advice or answers to concerns outside the question.

Comment: every one has been extremely helpful gone out there way to help me and done a good deed I am very grateful for this and everyone that has helped thank you very much but as always you always get a twat making people waste there time these people are helpful and are a credit to this website they have gone out there way to help and do you see them complaining I have had great advice of some great people what did you do did you help no so in a polite way f**k off

Comment: and raed the reply in the question below this problem arose after this code was put in not a completely different question otherwise I would have posted it some where different get your facts right people like you make me livid get involved you don't even now what's going on EVERYTHING WORKED FINE TILL THIS not saying kasun did wrong he's been brilliant just hoping there is a bit of code to exclude my blog and catalogue sub domains from being included to the url rewrite if I stick it as another question people will not know what's been going on I think an apology would be nice

Comment: maybe I didn't quite write it right even so don't make me look a idiot I've done a pretty good job of that myself

Comment: I might have gone a bit overboard In what I have said and can see where you are coming from but I do think its a little extreme in what you are saying if your like the people I have meet on here then your probably very clever as well im new and don't know now where near what some of you do im not scamming nothing im just asking advice apologies for being rude and disrespect full sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using {Domain}/Chalkboards-and-Accessories/Budget-Framed-Chalkboards URL, 
I'm suggesting you should use {Domain}/**Products/Chalkboards-and-Accessories/Cafe-and-Rope-Barrier-Systems**, because in your site you are having URLs like {Domain}/?About.

Try this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^catalogue\.signalight\.co\.uk$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\.signalight\.co\.uk$

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/catalogue
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$                                    ?$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$                   ?$1=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$  ?$1=$2&SubCat=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)?$  ?$1=$2&SubCat=$3&Item=$4 [L]
```

Comment: hi this didnt seem to have no affect

Comment: hope .htaccess file placed on your root directory. And u should be accessing url like http://www.signalight.co.uk/Products/Chalkboards-and-Accessories/Cafe-and-Rope-Barrier-Systems

Comment: yeap they veiw like that but how once clicked thyrough my site ie products - displays -cafe rope barrier Systems- pole and rope barrier i think maybe you missed the next catagory cheers

Comment: yes, please try updated one. example url : http://www.signalight.co.uk/Products/Displays/Portable-Exhibition-Displays/Adjustable-Quick-Banner
http://www.signalight.co.uk/Products/Displays

Comment: you all well know what you are doing maybe i missing something here confused

Comment: thats the nuts so how when i select from website does it show in the url

Comment: sean, you have to modify all your menu links

Comment: ok the pages in question are formed via php and a datbase do i need to change the script

Comment: if your menu items saved in the database, yes you need to modify those urls. but be careful.

Comment: sounds like fun then thanks for your help im well impressed thanks

Comment: as an example your existing URL :http://www.signalight.co.uk/?Products=Pavement-Signs&SubCat=A-Boards   New URL  should be http://www.signalight.co.uk/Products/Pavement-Signs/A-Boards

Comment: tell you the truth i sort of a row with my web developer i can do all the design side but looking at the files here its like double dutch to me cannot find anything relating to how the urls are formed

Comment: first check file call header or menu which starts like  <div id="naviagtion_wrapper"> if found check for <ul>
      <li><a ...

Comment: ok done most of them just when you select products youre the man

Comment: jsut one thing if your still there

Comment: no worries sussed it thanks for all your help and every one else well happy with result spot on advice thanks

Comment: i'm here any more help i can give

Comment: HI AGAIN EVERYTHING WORKS FINE HOWEVER I ALSO HAVE 2 SUB DOMAINS blog.signalight.co.uk and catalogue.signalight.co.uk can only be accessed buy putting index.php after the domain have you any ideas many thanks sean

Comment: **This is an answer to a nonexistent question.** The posted question does not include any of the the concerns that supposedly resolves this answer.

Comment: it happened because of this answer I host with 123 and all my other websites are all together in same file  pretty sure that's not how its done its  a lot different to host gator so I think the code given to me is pukka but I might need a rule to exclude blog and catalogue from this as it seems to be applying to all my sites not just the main one  and this question was aimed at kasun because hes the one that figured it out the way I would have liked it so I hope he might have a fix for this or point us in the right direction

Comment: please try updated code. if you have any other sub domain you can add RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^catalogue\.signalight\.co\.uk$ and folder below that. you need to remove # (comment) if you need to exclude folder also

Comment: hi mate your are just too good works perfect well happy thanks for advice you have helped me loads thank you and thanks to all spot on

Comment: hi again im sure I am doing something wrong here I also have just started my friends site acbuildingsolutions.co.uk this file is in the public html folder with all my other sites unfornunatly his site noe redirects to mine should my site be separated or something or do I have to rewrite this as well folder is called ac_solutions sorry to be a pain I don't know if its me or being restrictive in 123-reg?

Comment: I should have read that properly done a lot of that this morning as you may tell I have just tried what you said and I can now view that site again thanks for your help and wish you all the best

Answer (score 0):

[this is a nice artical for basics url rewriting.](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Comment: This may be a good article, but merely suggesting it, you are not really answering the question. Maybe you can improve your answer by adding examples from that article to your post. Otherwise this is only a good comment, but a poor answer.